# How to fix Bootstrap row in col overflow rounded.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap row in col, overflow. Red area in focus. What is it problem?

[Click in show picture](http://prntscr.com/dtrtf9)

**Code:**

```
<div class="row" style="background: red;">
        <div class="col-sm-0"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 columnthree" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
            <div class="row " style="">
                <img src="images/contact.png">
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="">
                <img src="images/contact.png">
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="">
                <img src="images/contact.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 columnthree" style="background: #DDDAD3; overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="">
                <p style="text-align: justify; font-family: 'Oswald'; padding: 5px;">
                    laminat parke ustası istanbul, silivrideki parkeciler, parke ustası beylikdüzü, ümraniye laminat parke ustası, samandıra parkeci, parke ustası arıyorum,sistre parke cilası yapan usta, esenlerde parkeci, parkeci bostancı, altunizade parkeci,çerkezköy parkeciler,
        esenyurt parkeciler, gaziosmanpaşa parkeci, bayrampasa parke ustası, kağıthane yakın parkeci, unkapani parkeciler,parkeci ikitelli, yenibosna parkeciler, pendik civarinda parkeci,parkeci istanbul, parkeci kavacık, zeytinburnu laminant parkeciler
        <span class="" style="text-align: justify; font-family: 'Oswald'; padding: 5px;">, bayrampaşada parkeci,avcılardaki parkeciler,parkeci çekmeköy ,anadolu yakasında parke ustasi, parke ustası mecidiyeköy,  kucukcekmecede parkeciler, zekeriyaköy parke ustası, kurtköy    parkeci, istanbul lamine parkeciler,parkeci ustam,tozsuz sistre cila,sistre cila ustası,parkeci  maltepe,maltepede parkeci,usta              
        </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can we give you solution of your problem without looking at your code? What do you think?

Comment: Code is sharing now. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Before asking questions, please go through the topics at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . Mainly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aong9q97/) of your code but I don't see any problem there.. Plz create a working example where problem is visible.

Comment: http://www.gulparkeci.com/bootstrap/ site is uploaded this url. please show my code. I dont understand. I plan convert  web site to responsive web site . thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: All your div's seem to overlay the background of the ones above, this element doesn't have any background set. Remove the margin-top: 5px; and add background: #fff; and you're good to go!]
All your div's seem to overlay the background of the ones above, this element doesn't have any background set. Remove the margin-top: 5px; and add background: #fff; and you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you. Well done. Bootstrap amazing, must responsive design. This site be main site and sub domain (mobile jquery). This problem solved by bootstrap.

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark as the correct answer :)